# Select all checkbox of table on click of the another table checkbox using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html, redux

I have checkboxes for each `td` in a table. Now, I have another table which has one checkbox. On checking this, I want to select all other checkboxes of first table.

Here is the code,

```
<tr key={key}>
    <td align="center"> <input type="checkbox" name="myTextEditBox" value="checked" /></td>
    <td>{item.technology}</td>
</tr>
```

for second table I did,

```
handleCheckBox = () => {
    console.log("callling the handle change");
    this.setState({
      isCheckd: !this.state.isCheckd
    })
}

constructure(props) {
    this.state = { isCheckd: false }
    <td className="text-right mr-1"><input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.isCheckd} onChange={this.handleCheckBox}  /></td>
}
```

Now, In this click handler works. But, now how do I select all other checkboxes of another table, without using jquery.

Can any one help me with this ?

Tried solution -

```
state = { dynamicProp: {},  isCheckd: false,}

    handleCheckBox = () => {
        this.setState({
          isCheckd: !this.state.isCheckd
        }, () => {
          this.props.jobs.forEach((item) =>
            this.setState(prevState => ({
              dynamicProp: {
                ...prevState.dynamicProp,
                [item.jdName]: prevState.isCheckd
              }
            })
            ))
        });
      }

      handleTableCheckboxChange = (e) => {
        const target = e.target.name;
        const checked = e.target.checked;
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          dynamicProp: {
            ...prevState.dynamicProp,
            [target]: checked
          }
        }), () => {
          const result = this.allTrue(this.state.dynamicProp);
          this.setState({
            isCheckd: result ? false : true
          })
        })
      }



 allTrue(obj) {
    for (var o in obj)
      if (!obj[o]) return true;
    return false;
  }
```

and then passing all the props to the child element. Now, the problem I am facing now is in the handleTableCheckboxChange method where I am not getting the way you used filter to get the unchecked element. and then the select all check will get changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not understand your code well so I understand it from what you have written. And then I have created a working example for you. Hope it can help you!

> **UPDATED CODE**

```js
const Table=(props)=>(
   <table>
   {
      props.items.map((item, i) => (
        <tr key={i}>
           <td>
             <input type="checkbox"  checked={props.parentState[item.name]}  name={item.name} onChange={props.handleChange} />
           </td>
           <td>{item.value}</td>
        </tr>
      ))
   }
   </table>
);

class App extends React.Component {
    items = [
        {
            value: 'EN',
            name: 'field1'
        },
        {
            value: 'IT',
            name: 'field2',
        }
    ];

    state = {
        checkAll: false,
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Check All
                <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleCheckAll} checked={this.state.checkAll}/>
                <Table
                   handleChange={this.handleChange}
                   items={this.items}
                   parentState={this.state}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }

    handleCheckAll = () => {
        this.setState({
            checkAll: !this.state.checkAll
        }, () => {
            this.items.forEach((item) => this.setState({ [item.name]: this.state.checkAll}))
      });
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.checked
        }, () => {
             const uncheckedItems = this.items.filter((item) => !this.state[item.name])

             this.setState({
                  checkAll: uncheckedItems.length === 0?true:false
             });
            
        });
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, I can do this way as well, I can select all on the basis of that prop only. But then that td can also be individually select, in your solution we can not select it individually

Comment: you can take an onChange for those td and manage those state based on the checkbox name property. in onChangeHandler you can update the state for each checkbox dynamically. this.setState({[e.target.name]:checkedValue}); and then you can check if all fields value is checked checck all checkbox also should get checked

Comment: So, Here we are already using checked={this.state.checkAll}  this state prop then How do we use another state prop with the checked only

Comment: give unique name property to each checkbox and then this.setState({[e.target.name]:e.target.checked});

Comment: let me make it for you.

Comment: i have added the updated code. there can be some mistakes but you can fix it by giving it some time.

Comment: Hey @hardik, I have tried this. Actually,  in this  {this.state[item.name]}   in this part , Here it is in the same container. but my table is in the another component and manipulation is in the container. and I am passing all this function as a props to this component. So, How do I pass this particular state as a prop to that component ?

Comment: You should create all the handler function in parent component and passed those handler functions and state to the child component where you can show the table data. By doing this, child component will behave as the stateless/presentational component which will show the details based on the props.

Comment: I am doing the same Here. But the only thing is about that  {this.state[item.name]}  as it is creating the state of that element using this and  How do I pass this to the child component as a props because I can not pass a single state , as it will be for each and every element .

Comment: I have updated the code what I tried. could  please check

Comment: @GaneshKaspate I have updated the code! Hope it will work for you.

Comment: @HardikChaudhary can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69167439/custom-table-checkbox-with-select-all-react  this link, I am facing almost the same issue but using reactHooks. Not sure how to manage in them.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample code. Obviously i haven't covered all the fail cases. Still you will get an idea about how that can be done.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class CheckboxIndex extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isChecked : false,
            allTDS : [
                {name:"name 1",value:false},
                {name:"name 2",value:false},
                {name:"name 3",value:false},
                {name:"name 4",value:false},
                {name:"name 5",value:false},
                {name:"name 6",value:false},
                {name:"name 7",value:false}
            ]
        }
    }

    handleCheckBox = () => {
        this.setState({isChecked: !this.state.isChecked});
        let tempTDS = this.state.allTDS;
        for (let i =0; i < tempTDS.length; i++){
            tempTDS[i].value = !this.state.isChecked;
        }
        this.setState({allTDS : tempTDS});
    };

    render(){
        let listOfTR;
        if(this.state.allTDS.length){
            listOfTR = this.state.allTDS.map((item,index)=>{
                return(
                    <tr key={item.name}>
                        <td>
                            <label htmlFor={item.name}>
                            <input id={item.name} checked={item.value} type="checkbox"
                                   onChange={()=>{
                                       let tempObj = this.state.allTDS;
                                       tempObj[index].value = !tempObj[index].value;
                                       this.setState({allTDS:tempObj});
                                   }}/>{item.name}
                            </label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                )
            })
        }
        return(
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="allTDS">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="allTDS" name="all" checked={this.state.isChecked}
                               onChange={this.handleCheckBox}/> All
                    </label>

                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                        {listOfTR}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.setState({
      isCheckd: !this.state.isCheckd
    })
```

In this case, the `isCheckd` value in state corresponds to one checkbox. To select all other checkboxes of another table you have to update the values set in setState to all the values that correspond to all the boxes you want checked.

So if you have another 3 checkboxes who's values correspond to `isCheckd1, isCheckd2, and isCheckd3` in state then your handler would be:

```
this.setState({
          isCheckd1: true,
          isCheckd2: true,
          isCheckd3: true
        })
```

Comment: Actually, another table is rendering using the map

Comment: it is like, user can check that checkboxes individually or else user can select all using the select all

Comment: Sure, so the select all will need its own handler function and that function will need to update the state of all of the value that corresponds to the checkboxes you want updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
class CheckboxTest extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selectAll: false,
      data1: false,
      data2: false
    };
    this.selectAll = this.selectAll.bind(this);
    this.selectField = this.selectField.bind(this);
  }
  selectAll() {
    this.setState({
      data1: !this.state.selectAll,
      data2: !this.state.selectAll,
      selectAll: !this.state.selectAll
    });
  }
  selectField(event) {
    if (event.target.value === "data1")
      this.setState({ data1: !this.state.data1 });
    else this.setState({ data2: !this.state.data2 });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <input
                  checked={this.state.data1}
                  onChange={this.selectField}
                  type="checkbox"
                  name="myTextEditBox1"
                  value="data1"
                />
              </td>
              <td>data 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <input
                  checked={this.state.data2}
                  onChange={this.selectField}
                  type="checkbox"
                  name="myTextEditBox2"
                  value="data2"
                />
              </td>
              <td>data 2</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <input
                  onChange={this.selectAll}
                  type="checkbox"
                  name="myTextEditBox1"
                  value="all"
                />
              </td>
              <td>Click all</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You can use the state for implementing this. Maintain state for each checkbox field and when the checkbox is changed trigger a method to set the state according to your conditions

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach. you can select both the individual and check all checkbox.

```js
    class App extends React.Component {
        items = ['EN', 'IT', 'FR', 'GR', 'RU'];
        state = {
          checkAll: false,
          items : [
           {'label': 'EN', 'checked': false},
           {'label': 'IN', 'checked': false}, 
           {'label': 'FR', 'checked': false},   
          ]
        };

        render() {
            return (
              <div>
                Check All
                <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleCheckAll} />
                <table>
                    {
                        this.state.items.map((item, i) => (
                            <tr key={i}>
                                <td>
                                  <input type="checkbox" checked={item.checked} />
                                </td>
                                <td>{item.label}</td>
                            </tr>
                        ))
                    }
                </table>
              </div>
            );
        }

        handleCheckAll = () => {
          let checkAll = !this.state.checkAll;
          let items = this.state.items;
          items.map((item, i) => {
            item.checked = checkAll;
          });
          this.setState({
            checkAll, 
            items
          });
        }
    }
```